# How to use Python in solving Lambert W function?

Tags: python

I am working on this function named lambert W function. It is usually applied when questions of the format `2^x= 5x` comes in and the property `xe^x=y` then `x=w(y)` where `w` is Lambert function. Although MATLAB can effectively dissolve it, but I also want to see if  Python can be used to get same quality result.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `scipy`. The function [`scipy.special.lambertw`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.lambertw.html) solves the Lambert W function branch numerically.

```
from scipy.special import lambertw

y = lambertw(2)

print(y) # (0.8526055020137254+0j)
```